# h5py installation - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: h5py

I am having trouble in installing h5py on my Windows machine. I am getting an error message that says: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.". I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain how to fix this issue.

Here is the complete log:

```
    Downloading/unpacking h5py
    Running setup.py egg_info for package h5py
running egg_info
writing requirements to pip-egg-info\h5py.egg-info\requires.txt
writing pip-egg-info\h5py.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\h5py.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\h5py.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\h5py.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\h5py.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6.1 in   c:\program files (x86)\enthought\canopy32\app\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages (from h5py)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Cython>=0.17 in c:\program files (x86)\enthought\canopy32\app\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages (from h5py)
Downloading/unpacking six (from h5py)
Running setup.py egg_info for package six
running egg_info
writing pip-egg-info\six.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\six.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\six.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\six.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation\_build'
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\six.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
Source in c:\users\ibm_admin\build\six has version 1.9.0, which satisfies requirement six (from h5py)
Installing collected packages: h5py, six
Running setup.py install for h5py
Running command C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\build\\h5py\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-05nf1z-record\install-record.txt
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
********************************************************************************
                       Summary of the h5py configuration

    Path to HDF5: None
    HDF5 Version: '1.8.4'
     MPI Enabled: False
Rebuild Required: False

********************************************************************************
Executing cythonize()
Autodetection skipped [[Error 126] The specified module could not be found]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\build\h5py\setup.py", line 140, in <module>
    cmdclass = CMDCLASS,
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup_build.py", line 172, in run
    self.extensions = cythonize(self._make_extensions(config),
  File "setup_build.py", line 72, in _make_extensions
    import numpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 168, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Complete output from command C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\build\\h5py\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-05nf1z-record\install-record.txt:
running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext
```

---

```
                   Summary of the h5py configuration



Path to HDF5: None

HDF5 Version: '1.8.4'

 MPI Enabled: False

 Rebuild Required: False
```

---

```
 Executing cythonize()

 Autodetection skipped [[Error 126] The specified module could not be found]

 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

 File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\build\h5py\setup.py", line 140, in <module>

 cmdclass = CMDCLASS,

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

 dist.run_commands()

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

 self.run_command(cmd)

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

 cmd_obj.run()

 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run

 return orig.install.run(self)

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

 self.run_command('build')

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

 self.distribution.run_command(command)

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

 cmd_obj.run()

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

 self.run_command(cmd_name)

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

 self.distribution.run_command(command)

 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

 cmd_obj.run()

 File "setup_build.py", line 172, in run

 self.extensions = cythonize(self._make_extensions(config),

 File "setup_build.py", line 72, in _make_extensions

 import numpy

 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 168, in <module>

 from . import add_newdocs

 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>

 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>

 from .polynomial import *

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>

 from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv

 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>

 from .linalg import *

 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 29, in <module>

 from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg

 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

 ----------------------------------------
 Command C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\build\\h5py\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-05nf1z-record\install-record.txt failed with error code 1
 Exception information:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 126, in main
self.run(options, args)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 228, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1100, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 572, in install
cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 255, in call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode))
 InstallationError: Command C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\build\\h5py\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-05nf1z-record\install-record.txt failed with error code 1
```